# RazorGenerator problems whne running under Medium trust level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using RazorGenerator to precompile the view. It works gerat in Full trust level. However my app runs in Shared hosting and thus requires to run under Medium trust.

I get the following error message: 
*

> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_Location() +100
>   RazorGenerator.Mvc.PrecompiledMvcEngine..ctor(Assembly assembly) +83
>   RGMvcApp.App_Start.RazorGeneratorMvcStart.Start() +109

*

It happens when defining/adding the new precompiled mvc view engine at App_Start.

There must be a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've fixed it right away. Download the latest version.